# How do I display data on detailpage in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a beers list page that displays all the list of beers.
I've made a button that should link to the detail page of that particular beer

in the router, I made a route for this :

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/:beerId/BeerDetails",
    name: "BeerDetails",

    props: true,
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../components/BeerDetails.vue"),
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

and in Beers component, I made the link

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <b-card
      v-bind:key="beer.id"
      v-for="beer in beers"
      :img-src="beer.image_url"
      :alt="beer.name"
      img-top
      tag="article"
      style="max-width: 22rem  ;"
      class="mb-2"
    >
      <b-card-text class="c-text">
        <h4 class="title">{{ beer.name }}</h4>
        <p>{{ beer.ingredients.malt[0].name }}</p></b-card-text
      >

      <router-link :to="{ name: 'BeerDetails', params: { beerId: beer.id } }">
        <b-button variant="primary">View Beer details</b-button></router-link
      >
    </b-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  name: "Beers",
  props: ["beers"],
};
</script>
```

so when I click the button and look in vue dev tools it shows me that props are beerId

but I don't have access to any other properties when for example I do {{beerId.name}}
so can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how I fix it?

Comment: You can add the entire beer object as a property. this will be used as the component props, `params: { beerId: beer.id }, props: { beer }`. Then you should have access to `this.beer` in your component

Comment: I tried your suggestion but when i use this.beer.name then it says in vue devtools props beer is undefined .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are passing an ID (most probably an INT) not an object.

```
 params: { beerId: beer.id }
```

so you can access an integer (the ID), that has no properties.
If you want to access all the properties, you should pass and object

```
 params: {beerId: beer.id, beer: beer }
```

Passing the ID only, make sense if you are loading the specific beer details in a second request, eg when the beer page is mounted

Comment: i want to load  the specific beer details of that single beer i click on, but i also want to acces all the properties of that specific beer. and for some reason it doesnt pass the prop of beer

Comment: i also have done that, but when i reload, the object disappears ...

Comment: Thats normal because the store get emptied on refresh. To store the values, you should set in the browser.storage or in a cookie the latest app store.state.

Comment: iI have started using vuex now to store my fetched data in store, so how would i store this single beer now?

Comment: To add to the store you use mutations, that are the only available way to change the state. If you want to persist the data, that's a different story (like when you refresh the page), and you should use the browser-storage or a cookie to store this infos, 
Take a look here: 

https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-permanently-save-data-with-vuex-localstorage-in-your-vue-app-f1d5c140db69

Comment: all i want is to persist the data, but the example you left let me more confused :P

Comment: Your question is about displaying data. Not storing. Open a new topic for this.